# Botium informations are available but whats the happy path to setup up alexa skill starting point of Botium

Tags: testing, jasmine, mocha.js, chatbot, alexa-voice-service

What needs to be setup first then the second level what needs to be done .
Eg :

1. Install botium in vs code with package.json with dependencies

> "chai": "^4.2.0",
>
> "mocha": "^6.1.4",
>
> "botium-bindings": "^2.0.13",
>
> "botium-cli": "^0.0.50",
>
> "botium-connector-alexa-avs": "^0.0.3",
>
> "botium-connector-alexa-smapi": "^0.0.5"

2.In vs code Cmd ->node modules ->bin

> botium-cli init
>   botium-cli run

3.Botium.json file is available in node modules-> bin

4.Add the required dependencies (**sample botium.json file for alexa required**)

5.Define test cases (The below is for IBM watson.Need the same for amazon alexa)
[https://chatbotsmagazine.com/5-steps-automated-testing-of-chatbots-in-eclipse-ef4c3dcaf233][1]

6.Setup Botium box (This i know in browser with npmjs steps i've done it)

7.Setup Botium-bindings(where does this happen in IDE like eclipse or vs code)

So a happy path of installation steps is required .Now all we have is raw information which can't be connected together to find the start and end point

https://chatbotsmagazine.com/5-steps-automated-testing-of-chatbots-in-eclipse-ef4c3dcaf233

Answer (score 0):

First step, install Botium-CLI and connector:

```
> npm install -g botium-cli
> npm install -g botium-connector-alexa-smapi
> botium-cli init
> botium-cli run
```

Second step, connect your Alexa Skill to Botium by adapting the botium.json file. This requires multiple steps, all of them are described [here](https://github.com/codeforequity-at/botium-connector-alexa-smapi#connecting-amazon-alexa-skills-api-to-botium) (Install ask-cli, retrieve credentials, copy to botium.json).

For an introduction what Botium is and how to get started writing test cases, I recommend the [Botium in a nutshell](https://medium.com/@floriantreml/botium-in-a-nutshell-part-1-overview-f8d0ceaf8fb4) blog series.